# Multiple IF arguments layered between cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I've found a lot of good help here before so I'm turning towards you with this problem that i can't find a fitting solution to.

I'm working to summarize data from a survey done with google forms and have asked the respondents a series of questions that was meant to be exclusive so if they answered "no" Q1 they wouldn't answer "yes" to Q2. It turned out my questions wasn't that good formulated so now i need your help to figure out who has answered "yes" followed by "yes" on the next question in a series of four total. 
Each questions is in a separate column so what i want to do is make excel give output 4 if respondent has answered "yes" consequently on all four questions, i.e `b2=1 and c2=1 and d2= 1 and e2=1`, and grading downwards with 0 if respondent answered 0 to Q1.

```
=if(b2=1(AND;c2=1(AND;d2=1(AND;e2=1;[1];[0])[0])[0])[0])
```

Comment: This is not how [`AND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9) works in Excel. That said, I would filter the data or use a `COUNTIF`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a combination of `IF()` and `COUNTIFS()`

If the answer in B2 is "no" then the score is set to zero, this can be achieved like so...

`=IF(B2="no",0)`

...else count all the responses that = "yes"...

`COUNTIFS(B2:E2,"yes")`

...put these together to get...

`=IF(B2="no",0,COUNTIFS(B2:E2,"yes"))`

Here is a quick table showing the output with the above formula in column F, titled Results:

[image]

I hope I have understood correctly and that this helps you out

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I think you understood it correctly but if i understand that formula correctly a Q1 yes followed by Q2 no and Q3 yes and Q4 no would still count as 2 so i think the  gentleman below here suits my case better. Still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting the question as saying, if you encounter a zero ignore any 1's to the right and don't go any further. So the formula would look for the first zero like this:

```
 =IFERROR(MATCH(0,D1:G1,0)-1,4)
```

If there are no zeroes, they must be all 1's so it returns 4.

[image]